# Clojure: LOG4J 1.2.16 & SLF4J 1.5.6 clashing with clj-tika and ring-middleware-logger

Tags: java, maven, clojure, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to use `clj-tika` and `ring-middleware-logger` in the same project. If I use either of them, everything compiles and works as expected.

However, as soon as I start using both at the same time, I am getting this error at compile time:

```
CompilerException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
```

Normally this means that SLF4J is not in the classpath. However, if I do a `lein classpath` in my project folder, I can clearly see:

```
C:\Users\Proprietaire\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.6\slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
```

So, it should be something else.

Then I ran: `mvn dependency:tree` to see if there could be SLF4J compatibility issues, and here is what I got for `ring-middleware-logger`:

```
[INFO] +- ring.middleware.logger:ring.middleware.logger:jar:0.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- onelog:onelog:jar:0.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:tools.logging:jar:0.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- clj-logging-config:clj-logging-config:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- swank-clojure:swank-clojure:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.clojars.pjlegato:clansi:jar:1.3.0:compile
```

And for `Tika`:

```
[INFO] +- clj-tika:clj-tika:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-tika:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:jar:tests:0.1:test,provided
[INFO] |     +- edu.ucar:netcdf:jar:4.2-min:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-dom:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:c
ompile
[INFO] |     +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:jar:1.0-RC-1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.11:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:jar:2.4.0-beta-1:compile
[INFO] |     +- de.l3s.boilerpipe:boilerpipe:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- rome:rome:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:jar:1.0.3:com
```

So, one use LOG4J and the other one SLF4J. If I stop using one of these packages, I do not get that error, as soon as I start using both I start getting the one above...

I am not a Java developer, so I am kind of stuck to fix this error. I have the intuition that I can probably make something available in my classpath or something such that the compiler finds it.

In any case, I am not sure why adding `ring-middleware-logger` conflict with `Tika` when none use the same packages (even if they are probably related in ways I don't know).

Comment: you need two slf4j jars. i think the binder class you're missing is from an impl jar that is different from the api jar you show. see if the slf4j impl jar is on the classpath and add it if not.

Comment: @nathan-hughes good thanks! After you said that, I looked at the `org.clojure:tools.logging:jar` library which is required by the middleware logger application. Then looking at its [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/pom.xml) file, I see: `slf4j-log4j12` version `1.6.2`. Is this what you meant? And could this be the problem? (incompatibility between the two SLF4J versions? If so, how could I fix that?

Comment: sounds likely. if this was maven you could tell it to use a specific version, i am not up to speed on Lein but I assume it must have a way to do that too.

Comment: @nathan-hughes well `lein` is based on `maven` so we should be able to fix that the maven way. However, I don't know how this could be done in maven, so I guess this is why I am stuck. So, what I would have to do is to fix `tools.logging`'s `pom.xml` file to use slf4j 1.5.6 instead? Or to update `Tika` to 1.6.2? (the problem with Tika is that I used its package from a maven repo, so not sure if this can be fixed using maven itself?)

Comment: yes, you need to make sure all the slf4j artifacts are compatible versions. i would try explicitly naming the 1.6.2 version as a dependency and get everything using that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @nathan-hughes for the pointers. Here is the final resolution of this issue.

The problem I had is that I didn't initially saw with the `maven` dependencies report that the `org.clojure:tools.logging:jar` library was including the `slf4j` jar version 1.6.2, which I found on the project's GitHub [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/pom.xml) file.

Then the next question was: how can we fix this slf4j incompatibilities issues? As @nathan-hughes suggested, just to make the version 1.6.2 a dependency.

So, what I did is simple to add the following two dependencies into my `project.clj` file:

```
[org.slf4j/slf4j-api "1.6.2"]
[org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 "1.6.2"]
```

(both are required otherwise logging won't work with the ring middleware)

Now that my Clojure project has these two libraries as direct dependencies, then this force the other packages to use it as well.

Now the compilation errors are gone, and the `ring.middleware.logger` package is working as expected, and Tika is not complaining neither which suggest that it works with this version of SLF4J without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are two slf4j jars, an api jar that the library depends on, and the implementation jar that the application uses. This is from the Libraries section of the [slf4j manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html):

> Authors of widely-distributed components and libraries may code against the SLF4J interface in order to avoid imposing an logging framework on their end-user. Thus, the end-user may choose the desired logging framework at deployment time by inserting the corresponding slf4j binding on the classpath, which may be changed later by replacing an existing binding with another on the class path and restarting the application. This approach has proven to be simple and very robust.
>
> As of SLF4J version 1.6.0, if no binding is found on the class path, then slf4j-api will default to a no-operation implementation discarding all log requests. Thus, instead of throwing a NoClassDefFoundError because the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class is missing, SLF4J version 1.6.0 and later will emit a single warning message about the absence of a binding and proceed to discard all log requests without further protest. For example, let Wombat be some biology-related framework depending on SLF4J for logging. In order to avoid imposing a logging framework on the end-user, Wombat's distribution includes slf4j-api.jar but no binding. Even in the absence of any SLF4J binding on the class path, Wombat's distribution will still work out-of-the-box, and without requiring the end-user to download a binding from SLF4J's web-site. Only when the end-user decides to enable logging will she need to install the SLF4J binding corresponding to the logging framework chosen by her.
>
> Basic rule Embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a library declares a transitive dependency on a specific binding, that binding is imposed on the end-user negating the purpose of SLF4J. Note that declaring a non-transitive dependency on a binding, for example for testing, does not affect the end-user.
>
> SLF4J usage in embedded components is also discussed in the FAQ in relation with logging configuration, dependency reduction and testing.

Since you're using 1.5 version of the api jar, you're seeing it throw the NoClassDefFoundError. It sounds like you have a library using the 1.5.6 version of the api jar that you're trying to use with the 1.6.2 version of the implementation jar.

There is a [compatibility report](http://www.slf4j.org/compatibility.html) on the slf4j website but it appears to not be updated yet for 1.6 or later. I would expect you'd have better chances getting 1.6.2 to work with the 1.5.6 version than the opposite (if the logger tool is using 1.6-specific features then downgrading the version won't work). I'd try naming the 1.6.2 version as an explicit dependency and see if that works.

Comment: good thanks! I was writing the definitive answer to my question as I saw this answer of your. That was the issue, and Tika seems to be compatible with 1.6.2, so everything is working as expected now!